# SQL Server OPENJSON returns 1900-01-01 for date type when empty string is passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, open-json

When parsing JSON string using OPENJSON in SQL Server, if date field is empty, SQL returns 1900-01-01.

```
DECLARE @dt [date]
SELECT @dt=dt 
FROM OPENJSON('{"dt":""}')
WITH (dt [date] '$.dt')
PRINT @dt
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01
```

How can I prevent this from happening? One way I could think of is to check the resulting value and reset to NULL if it is '1900-01-01'. Although I do not expect actual date to be ever 1900-01-01 but this does not look right to me. Am I missing something in the SQL syntax?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. It [already happens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89945/5203) with `declare @dt date = ''; select @d;`. If your json may contain empty strings in place of dates instead of nulls, extract them as `varchar`, convert empty strings to nulls and then convert to dates.

Comment: SQL Server converts empty string to '1900-01-01'. You will need pass null in the json string to avoid validations. For example: {"dt":null}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the value of `dt` being returned isn't a `NULL` but `''`, which as a date is `1900-01-01`. Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'');
```

You could use `NULLIF` around the value of `dt`:

```
SELECT @dt = NULLIF(dt,'')...
```